# How to deploy / migrate an existing django app / project to a production server on Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I have a basic django app ([Newsdiffs](https://github.com/ecprice/newsdiffs))that runs just fine at `localhost:8000` with `python website/manage.py runserver` but I'd like to migrate it to Heroku and I can't figure out what my next step is.

I thought getting it running locally would translate to running it on Heroku, but I'm realizing that `python website/manage.py runserver` is launching the dev settings and I'm not sure how to tell it to use the main settings.

All that is in my Procfile is this:

web: python website/manage.py runserver

Locally, that works fine, though it launches it at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ which is probably not what I want on Heroku. So how do I figure out where to set the hostname and port? I don't see either in the app anyplace.

Comment: Check in settings.py . Debug = flase .. some settings might be their..

Comment: Why do you think to need to set the hostname and port? You don't. But you do need to actually read the very comprehensive documentation on Heroku's site about running Django.

Comment: For example, I can't imagine what gave you the idea of putting runserver in your Procfile. You need to use gunicorn there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks. I did actually read the extensive Heroku documentation and launch a django app successfully. But this django app isn't in wsgi, so I can't use gunicorn unless I rewrite/rewrap it.

Comment: What? All Django apps are "in wsgi". That's how Django works.

Comment: @DanielRoseman not, I'm discovering, if they just use Django's built in dev server.

Comment: Not true. The dev server is a WSGI server, just not a particularly powerful or well-featured one. But you still haven't said what the difference is between your app and one that's "in wsgi".

Comment: @DanielRoseman it isn't exactly "my app" -- I didn't write Newsdiffs, I'm just trying to get my own instance of it running. But ... they didn't list gunicorn as a requirement and there aren't any references to gunicorn in the code base, so that's one thing that I've found puzzling as I try to apply Heroku's Django documentation to this app.

Comment: I really don't understand your issue. gunicorn is a requirement for running on Heroku, not in dev. So you need to install it, along with the other dependencies for running on Heroku, as described in the [Heroku docs on Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django).

Comment: Backtracking a little bit, so I can get this sorted out piece by piece: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814227/where-is-hellodjango-wsgi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know some python and have a lot of experience building web apps in other languages but don't totally understand where Heroku fits, I highly recommend [Discover Flask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfpFUmV1d0w&list=PLLjmbh6XPGK4ISY747FUHXEl9lBxre4mM), which patched a lot of the holes in my understanding of how these pieces all fit together.

Some of the things that I worked out:

- you really do need an isolated virtual environment if you're going to deploy to Heroku, because Heroku installs Python modules from the requirements.txt file.
- Gunicorn is a web server, and you definitely need to run your app under Gunicorn or it won't run on Heroku.
- The ["Procfile"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) doesn't just give the command you use to run the app locally. And Heroku requires it. So if you've got an app that was built to run on Heroku and it doesn't include a Procfile, they left something out.
- You don't tell Heroku what your hostname is. When you run `heroku create` it should tell you what your domain name is going to be. And every time you run `git push heroku master` (or whatever branch you're pushing, maybe it isn't `master`), Heroku will (try to) restart your app.
- Heroku [doesn't support sqlite](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#disk-backed-storage). You have to run your Production DB in Postgres.

This doesn't directly answer my question, but it does fill in some of the missing pieces that were making it hard for me to even ask the right question. RTFM notwithstanding. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have just drawn this list for myself two days ago.
It was put together after having followed the steps described in [Heroku's help pages for python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction).

It's by no means definitive nor perfect, and it will change, but it's a valid trace, since I was able to put the site online.

Some issues remain, to be checked thoroughly, e.g. the location of the `media/` directory where files are uploaded should/could live outside your project for security reasons (now it works, but I have noticed if the dyno sleeps then the files are not reached/displayed by the template later).
The same goes for the `staticfiles/` directory (although this one seems to work fine).

Also, you might want to set django's debug mode to false.

So here it is:

**My first steps to deploy an EXISTING django application to Heroku**

ASSUMPTIONS:

a) your django project is in a virtual environment already

b) you have already collected all your project's required packages with

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and committed it to git

```
git add requirements.txt
git commit -m 'my prj requirements'
```

0) Activate your project's virtual environment

```
workon xyz  #using virtualenvwrapper
```

then go to your django project's directory (DPD for short) if not already taken there

```
cd ~/prj/xyz  (or cdproject with virtualenvwrapper if setup properly)
```

and create a new git branch for heroku twiddling to prevent messing things up

```
git checkout -b he
```

1) Create the app on heroku

```
heroku create xyz
```

that also adds heroku as a remote of your repo

2) Add the needed packages to requirements.txt

```
vi requirements.txt
```

add

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-postgrespool==0.3.0
gunicorn==19.3.0
psycopg2==2.6
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
static3==0.5.1
whitenoise==2.0.3
```

3) Install all dependencies in the local venv

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --allow-all-external
```

4) Setup the heroku django settings

```
cd xyz
```

create a copy

```
cp setting.py settings_heroku.py
```

and edit it

```
vi settings_heroku.py

import os
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["DJANGO_SECRET_KEY"]
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

replace django's std db cfg with

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_postgrespool'
```

and

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'xyz.wsgi_heroku.application'
```

5) Configure the necessary environment variables (heroku configs)

edit the `.env` file

```
vi .env
```

e.g.

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=whatever
EMAIL_HOST_USER=youruser@gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=whateveritis
```

and/or set them manually if needed (in my case `.env` had no effect, wasn't loaded apparently, and had to set the vars manually for now)

```
heroku config:set DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=whatever
heroku config:set EMAIL_HOST_USER=youruser@gmail.com
heroku config:set EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=whateveritis
```

6) Create a separate wsgi file for heroku

```
cd xyx
cp wsgi.py wsgi_heroku.py
```

and edit it to make it point to the right settings

```
vi wsgi_heroku.py
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xyz.settings_heroku")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

7) Make sure all the templates use

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

8) Define the Procfile file so that it points to the right wsgi

e.g.

```
cd ~/prj/xyz (DPD)
vi Procfile
```

add

```
web: gunicorn xyz.wsgi_heroku --log-file -
```

9) Collect all static content into DPD/staticfiles/

locally, make sure django points to the right wsgi settings

```
export WSGI_APPLICATION=blogger.wsgi_heroku.application
python manage.py collectstatic
```

10) add the changes to the local git repo (he branch)

```
git add --all .
git commit -m 'first 4 heroku'
```

11) check the whole thing works locally

```
heroku local # in heroku's help they also add `web`, not needed?!
```

12) push your code to heroku

```
git push heroku he:master
```

13) make sure a instance of the app is running

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

14) create the tables on the heroku DB

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Note: if you see a message that says, “You just installed Django’s auth system, which means you don’t have any superusers defined. Would you like to create one now?”, type no.

15) add the superuser to the heroku DB

```
heroku run bash
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

and fill in the details, as usual

16) Populate the DB with the necessary fixtures

```
heroku run python manage.py loaddata yourfile.json
```

17) Visit the website page on heroku's webserver

```
heroku open
```

or go to

```
https://xyz.herokuapp.com/
```

and the admin

```
https://xyz.herokuapp.com/admin/
```

and the DB

```
https://xyz.herokuapp.com/db
```

Useful commands:

- View the app's logs

  `heroku logs [--tail]`
- List add-ons deployed

  `heroku addons`

  and use one:

  `heroku addons:open <add-on-name>`
- Run a command on heroku (the remote env, where you are deploying)

  `heroku run python manage.py shell`
  `heroku run bash`
- Set a config var on Heroku

  `heroku config:set VARNAME=whatever`
- View the config vars that are set (including the DB's)

  `heroku config`
- View postgres DB details

  `heroku pg`

Comment: since migrations are idempotent, is there a way to make the migrate step run on deploy via the wsgi.py or settings file?