# Where is "hellodjango.wsgi"?

Tags: django, heroku, wsgi

I'm trying to assemble some of the [missing pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600341/how-to-deploy-migrate-an-existing-django-app-project-to-a-production-server) in my understanding of how to deploy a Django App to heroku, so that I can launch an instance of [Newsdiffs](https://github.com/ecprice/newsdiffs) on Heroku.

When I walk through the instructions for running [Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) they have you add a line to `Procfile` that reads thus: `web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -`

But there's no actual file *named* "hellodjango.wsgi" so ... in that tutorial, where is the "hellodjango.wsgi" module created?

And, perhaps more to the point, why is `heroku local` balking that I have `web.1  | : No module named newsdiffs.wsgi` when `newdsdiffs/wsgi.py` definitely exists.

I can launch the app locally with `python website/manage.py runserver` but if I do `gunicorn newsdiffs.wsgi` I get the following, which doesn't include any obvious indications (to my eye) of what I'm doing wrong:

```
(venv)amanda@mona:newsdiffs$ gunicorn newsdiffs.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 542, in spawn_workers
    time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/amanda/Public/newsdiffs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gunicorn` command takes the name of a Python module, not a path to a file. If `hellodjango.wsgi` is the name of the Python module, the corresponding file will be `hellodjango/wsgi.py` or `hellodjango/wsgi/__init__.py`.

This is the same syntax used to refer to a module when importing it, e.g. you would `import * from hellodjango.wsgi` to get access to the things defined in `hellodjango/wsgi.py`.

The `django-admin startproject` command will create a `wsgi.py` file in the same directory as the project's `settings.py` and `urls.py` files.

Comment: Hmm. I do have a file, `newsdiffs/wsgi.py` but `heroku local` says "No module named newsdiffs.wsgi" (Note: updated my question to clarify that.)

Comment: Can you run `gunicorn newsdiffs.wsgi` without `heroku local`?

Comment: There's not much to go on in that error. There might be something helpful in one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488891/gunicorn-errors-haltserver-haltserver-worker-failed-to-boot-3-django or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639907/gunicorn-errors-haltserver-haltserver-worker-failed-to-boot-3